# Filtering out Annotation Feature Classes using arcpy.da.Walk()?

Tags: arcpy, walk

Is there a way to use:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk():
```

to filter out annotation feature classes?

The help doesn't specify them as a type, which is strange because using the **[Feature Class Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000066000000)** returned by the Describe function, you can filter out annotation.

I'm hoping to walk through a geodatabase and grab everything but the annotation FC's.

Comment: Cross-posted from [Esri forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/95161-Filter-Out-Annotaion-Feature-Class-Using-arcpy.da.Walk%28%29)

Comment: Thanks Jason. He provided a very good answer in the cross post.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in a comment by @Mike on his question, there has been [code provided by @JasonScheirer](https://community.esri.com/thread/82795) at GeoNet that will do this:

```
def filter_function(walk):  
    for dirname, subdirs, items in walk:  
        new_items = []  
        for item in items:  
            description = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(dirname, item))  
            if description.dataType == "FeatureClass":  
                if description.featureType != "Annotation":  
                    new_items.append(item)  
            else:  
                new_items.append(item)  
        yield dirname, subdirs, new_items  

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in filter_function(arcpy.da.Walk(workspace)):  
    # Something interesting goes here
```